# Handling Promise rejection with catch while using await

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async-await, promise

I am using `await` to make the code cleaner, but I am not sure whether I am handling exceptions correctly.

An example while using azure-devops-node-api;

```
const foo = async() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ...
        ...
        const teams = await coreApiObject.getTeams(currProject.id)
                      .catch(err => { reject(err)  return })
        ...
        ...
    })  
}
```

In this code I am assuming, if there is a problem with promise call, foo() is going to return reject.

Comment: you need to wrap it into a try catch block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async` functions always return a promise, so you don't need to explicitly create one yourself. Any non-promise value returned from an `async` function is implicitly wrapped in a promise.

Inside the `foo` function, you just need to `await` the call `coreApiObject.getTeams(...)` and to catch and handle any error, use the `try-catch` block.

Your code can be simplified as shown below:

```
const foo = async() => {
   try {
      const teams = await coreApiObject.getTeams(currProject.id);
      return teams;
   } catch (e) {
      // handle error
   } 
}
```

If you want to the calling code to handle the error, then you can use one of the following options:

- Remove the `try-catch` block and just return the result of `coreApiObject.getTeams(...)`.

  ```
  const foo = async() => {
     return coreApiObject.getTeams(currProject.id);
  }
  ```

  Removing the `try-catch` block and just returning the call to `coreApiObject.getTeams(...)` will allow the calling code to handle the error because the promise returned by the `foo` function will get *resolved* to the promise returned by `coreApiObject.getTeams(...)`; this means that the fate of the promise returned by the `foo` function will depend on whatever happens to the promise returned by `coreApiObject.getTeams(...)`.

  If the promise returned by `coreApiObject.getTeams(...)` is rejected, promise returned by the `foo` function will also be rejected and hence the calling code will have a change to catch the promise rejection and handle it.
- Throw the error from the `catch` block.

  ```
  const foo = async() => {
     try {
        const teams = await coreApiObject.getTeams(currProject.id);
        return teams;
     } catch (error) {
        // throw the error
        throw error;
     } 
  }
  ```

  Other option is to throw the error from the `catch` block to make sure that the promise returned by the `async` function is *rejected*.

  If you don't throw the error or return a promise or a thenable that is rejected, returning any other value from the `catch` block will fulfil the promise returned by the `async` function with whatever value is returned inside the `catch` block.

Comment: You are saying if I sing a function as async and return a value, the value automatically will be wrapped in a promise object. Right?

Comment: In this case, what if I also want the caller function to handle the exception

Comment: mozilla.org says, "A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an exception thrown from, or uncaught within, the async function."